# How to make OSX Yosemite webviews work with ADFS

Tags: cocoa, single-sign-on, osx-yosemite, adfs, basic-authentication

I'm using a webview to host a log in page that redirects to an ADFS server to offer single sign on. This works on 10.9, but I noticed for OSX 10.10 I am able to get to the point where the ADFS server will present an http authentication challenge, the webview will show the default dialog to enter credentials, but after entering the credentials I never see the expected redirects that eventually allow the single sign on process to complete. Even if I cancel the webview prompt to login, I never receive a didReceiveResponse message (in the WebResourceLoadDelegate protocol).

Does anyone know of any changes in the webview for 10.10 that may cause it to stop sending/receiving requests/responses like this?

**Update:** It looks like this issue is a problem with WebViews and HTTP Basic Authentication in general. I have created a simple mac application with a single web view, and pointed it to a apache web server with a folder protected by an .htaccess file. While the app is able to successfully view the actual web page after the user enters their credentials in the login prompt on 10.9, on 10.10 this fails in the same manner as described above.